# Is there an easy way to temporarily turn off parts of the scenario?

Tags: repast-simphony

My aim is to temporarily turn off some of the Text Sinks for a specific batch run. My motive is that I want to save processing time and disk space. My wider aim is to easily switch not only between different text sinks but also parameter files, data loaders, etc.

A few things I've tried:

- manually put the xml-files linked to the text sinks in a different folder **-->** this creates an error message (that possibly can be ignored?) and does not serve my wider aim of having different charts/data loaders/displays/etc.
- create a completely new scenario-tree by copying the .rs folder and creating a new Run Configuration for that .rs folder **-->** if I want to change the parameters in all the scenarios at once, then I need to do it manually
- try to create a new scenario.xml file (i.e., scenario2.xml) in the hope this would turn up as an alternative in the scenario tree **-->** nothing turned up in the GUI

Thus: Is there another easy way to temporarily turn off parts of the scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we've done in the past is create different scenarios for each type of run (your second option). Regarding the parameters in the scenario folders, you could potentially run a script to copy the version you want to all the scenario folders so you don't have to manually adjust each one.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know other people came to the same conclusion. I have an awkward knowledge gap in coding anything I would normally do in Windows Explorer but my guess would be: make an extra class in the project that I can run independently and uses the Files.copy function.